# Gravity forms delete entry by ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'd like to delete a gravity forms entry by its ID. I  found that one can include the following in the functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'remove_form_entry' );
function remove_form_entry( $entry ) {
    GFAPI::delete_entry( $entry['id'] );
}
```

This function removes the entry straight after the form is submitted and the entry is added, but I don't want to remove EVERY entry.

Being new to wordpress and gravity forms, I'm not sure how to utilize the above to remove an entry by its ID.

I am used to php and mysql, so an an ad-hoc approach would be appreciated too, just not sure what tables to target if done manually.

Comment: You state that you don not "want to remove EVERY entry". What entries is it that you want to remove?

Answer (score 3):

To remove an entry using the Gravity Forms API you can use `GFAPI::delete_entry( $id );` where `$id` is the ID of the entry you want to delete.

In your example above you are passing the newly created entry ID to the method thus deleting the entry immediately after it has been created.